# Mask folder in output URL

Tags: .htaccess, directory, masking, phpbb3

I have this website, it is my primary domain, however the folder is actually /public_html/annexation.ca. This part is fine, I have an htaccess rule in my public_html folder to deal with that, so that it shows up as annexation.ca and not annexation.ca/annexation.ca.

But I also run a forum off of that website. The problem is that the phpbb software has an auto-direct after logon, logoff and in a couple of other instances. And when it does so it generates a URL like this:

http://annexation.ca/annexation.ca/community

This is not only cosmetically disruptive, but it also impacts the comment section at the bottom of each unique page, where I have Disqus running. What I need is to add a rule to the htaccess file in the root folder that will make these redirects be automatically translated into this again:

http://annexation.ca/community/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your .htaccess

```
## 301 Redirect Entire Directory
Redirect 301 /annexation.ca/community(.*) /community/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule on **top of other rules**:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+annexation\.ca/(community)([^\s?]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```